# select a image from gallery and add class to it and save it to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to select an image from multiple images, add a selected class to it and then save that image id or name to my database. Images are generated dynamically using php.

I want to:

1. image should be selected when the user clicks on the check mark.
2. add a selected class(green checkbox) to selected image by user
3. only 1 image can be selected
4. add selected image id or name to database when the save button is clicked

[image: this is how my images look]

```
<div class="gallery_grid uk-grid-width-medium-1-4 uk-grid-width-large-1-5" data-uk-grid="{gutter: 16}">
    <div class="uk-width-medium-3-10">
        <div>
            <div class="md-card md-card-hover">
                <div class="gallery_grid_item md-card-content">
                    <div class="uk-badge uk-badge-danger uk-position-absolute uk-position-top-left uk-margin-left uk-margin-top">&#8377; 455.00
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-badge uk-badge-success uk-position-absolute uk-position-top-right uk-margin-right uk-margin-top">
                        <i class="material-icons">&#xE86C;</i>
                    </div>
                    <img src="assets/img/gallery/Image01.jpg" alt="">                            
                    <div class="gallery_grid_image_caption">
                        <div class="gallery_grid_image_menu">
                            <i class="md-icon material-icons">&#xE876;</i>
                        </div>
                        <span class="gallery_image_title">In quia eos veniam aperiam ut.</span>
                        <span class="uk-text-muted uk-text-small">23 Jun 2016, 64KB</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-medium-3-10">
        <div>
            <div class="md-card md-card-hover">
                <div class="gallery_grid_item md-card-content">
                    <div class="uk-badge uk-badge-danger uk-position-absolute uk-position-top-left uk-margin-left uk-margin-top">&#8377; 455.00
                    </div>
                    <img src="assets/img/gallery/Image01.jpg" alt="">                            
                    <div class="gallery_grid_image_caption">
                        <div class="gallery_grid_image_menu">
                            <i class="md-icon material-icons">&#xE876;</i>
                        </div>
                        <span class="gallery_image_title">In quia eos veniam aperiam ut.</span>
                        <span class="uk-text-muted uk-text-small">23 Jun 2016, 64KB</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-medium-3-10">
        <div>
            <div class="md-card md-card-hover">
                <div class="gallery_grid_item md-card-content">
                    <div class="uk-badge uk-badge-danger uk-position-absolute uk-position-top-left uk-margin-left uk-margin-top">&#8377; 455.00
                    </div>                        
                    <img src="assets/img/gallery/Image01.jpg" alt="">                            
                    <div class="gallery_grid_image_caption">
                        <div class="gallery_grid_image_menu" data-uk-dropdown="{pos:'top-right'}">
                            <i class="md-icon material-icons">&#xE876;</i>
                        </div>
                        <span class="gallery_image_title">In quia eos veniam aperiam ut.</span>
                        <span class="uk-text-muted uk-text-small">23 Jun 2016, 64KB</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is example https://jsfiddle.net/o5sb7wLq/

example.html

```
<div class="container">
<img id='1' class="image" src="http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2014/04/10/11752526/gI_134971_best-image-web-hosting.png">
<img id='2' class="image" src="http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2014/04/10/11752526/gI_134971_best-image-web-hosting.png">
<img id='3' class="image" src="http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2014/04/10/11752526/gI_134971_best-image-web-hosting.png">
</div>
```

example.js

```
$(".image").on('click', function(){
    $('.image').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  sendToDatabase($(this).attr('id'));
});

function sendToDatabase(data) {
    //$.post(saveToDatabase.php,{id: data}, function(){
    //    post request to your controler in php 
    //});
}
```