# How to put an image that is already in-browser into a form

Tags: html, forms, multipartform-data

I want to let my users add an image to a form, similar to how they might upload an image from their browser, but I want them to be able to choose an image that is already in the browser on the page that I delivered to them.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Show a modal that has a gallery of images and let them choose one of them, on clicking save collect the index/unique id of the image and save the form.

Something like this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/35543772